# String comparision not working when compared against an item(concatenated string) in C# ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net

Kindly explain what's going on with this below code (//DOESN'T WORK sections)
I know it will work if I rather use Equals() instead of == operator. But I am missing some understanding here. Thanks.

**EDIT:** My goal here is not to make it work, rather want to understand what's going on at compiler/runtime level in detail.

```
        string first = "string1";
        string full = first + " string2";

        Debug.Assert(full == "string1 string2", "Expected to be same.");//WORKS
        Debug.Assert(first + " string2" == "string1 string2", "Expected to be same.");//WORKS

        var list = new ArrayList();
        list.Add(full);
        list.Add(first + " string2");

        Debug.Assert(list[0] == "string1 string2", "Expected to be same.");//DOESN'T WORK
        Debug.Assert(list[1] == "string1 string2", "Expected to be same.");//DOESN'T WORK

        list.Add("string1 string2");
        Debug.Assert(list[2] == "string1 string2", "Expected to be same.");//WORKS
```

Comment: Why are you even using `ArrayList`? it is only in the .NET framework for backward compatibility with .NET 1.1 programs and should not be used in new development.

Comment: Right! But this is not a production code. Just some random scenario I was working out while trying to understand what's going on at compiler/runtime level.

Comment: You can recreate the same situation by just storing the strings in a `object` instead of a `string`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the list is not generic, so you can´t compare an object with an string. It's better, something like this:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add(full);
list.Add(first + " string2");

Debug.Assert(list.ElementAt(0) == "string1 string2", "Expected to be same.");
```

You can use `string[]` as well.

Comment: But are we really comparing object with a string here? Because when I did  Console.WriteLine(list[0].GetType()); it says System.String. Wouldn't the compiler cast the value as a string after we add to the List/ArrayList even when they are generic?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because type of `list[0]` is Object.
If add ToString() method like this:
`Debug.Assert(list[0].ToString() == "string1 string2", "Expected to be same.");` it should work

Comment: Yeah, Could have agreed to this. But when I do a Console.WriteLine(list[0].GetType()); it says System.String. And BTW my goal is not to make it work. Just trying to understand why is this failing and what's happening under the hood